# Play Framework For Scala: [type BooksController is not a member of package controllers]

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I try to compile, but get a following compilation error on console

<>@7a6b9ggi8 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/books] ->

```
 play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[type BooksController is not a member of package controllers]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
 [info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/Play/PROJ_NAME/target/scala-2.11/classes...
 [error] /Users/Play/PROJ_NAME/conf/routes:18: type BooksController is not a member of package 

controllers
[error] GET     /books                      controllers.BooksController.index()
[error] /Users/Play/PROJ_NAME/conf/routes:18: type BooksController is not a member of package controllers
[error] GET     /books                      controllers.BooksController.index()
[error] /Users/Play/PROJ_NAME/conf/routes:18: type BooksController is not a member of package controllers
[error] GET     /books                      controllers.BooksController.index()
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application -
```

And BooksController is

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import play.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;
//
public class BooksController extends Controller{
    public Result index(){
        return TODO;
    }
}
```

and routes is

```
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
# An example controller showing how to use dependency injection
GET     /count                      controllers.CountController.count
# An example controller showing how to write asynchronous code
GET     /message                    controllers.AsyncController.message
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

#フォーム処理アクション
#POST   /send                       controllers.HomeController.send()

#book用
GET     /books                      controllers.BooksController.index()
#GET     /books/create               controllers.BooksController.create()
#GET     /books/:id                  controllers.BooksController.show(id: Integer)
#GET     /books/edit/:id             controllers.BooksController.edit(id: Integer)
#POST    /books/edit                 controllers.BooksController.update()
#POST    /books/create               controllers.BooksController.save()
#GET     /books/delete/:id           controllers.BooksController.destroy(id: Integer)

GET     /about/
```

I'm using Play Framework 2.5.10
How to debug this compilation error?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Hi! Is your controller perhaps a java-class and not a scala-class? I know that I've made the mistake myself of mixing that up. I'm thinking especially since you're getting this: **Compiling 4 Scala sources and 1 Java source**  and perhaps the package isn't correct. Maybe it should be **/app/controllers** perhaps easier for you to check in your ide

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked :D I guess I should've put it an answer then, but I got too scared. Really happy that I could help though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because your controller is a java-class and not a scala-class. I know that I've made the mistake myself of mixing that up.

I'm thinking especially since you're getting this: `Compiling 4 Scala sources and 1 Java source` and perhaps the package isn't correct. Maybe it should be `/app/controllers` perhaps easier for you to check in your ide.

Comment: For me, I had written `controller` instead of `controllers`.
Notice that it should match exactly the name of your package (the folder containing your controllers.